# Windows command : popd returns an error

Tags: batch-file

I am using a shortcut to launch a Windows script. The shortcut is configured the following way :

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "\\serverLocation\MyScript.bat"
```

I am using a shortcut because the script is located on a server and I want to avoid the "can't use UNC path" error.

Then the script is the following one :

```
@echo off

pushd %~dp0 
@echo "The following versions of the software are available"
set /A i = 1
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /d %%A in (*)  do (echo %%A)
popd
```

and popd returns the following error :

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

What am I doing wrong ? I don't get the error since popd effectively deletes the server disk created by the pushd command

Comment: Run ` echo %~dp0` to see what the path resolves to.

Comment: It seems %~dp0 returns the correct path

Comment: Apparently this is linked to the enabledelayedexpansion option because when removing it, the error disappears

Comment: @FenryrMKIII, the setlocal starts a new environment.  So once you are done with that environment you need to also have an endlocal.  The PUSHD command is only holding the previous directory in the first environment so the POPD command with throw an error.

Comment: I don't think the `popd` command caused the error. IMHO these are the executed steps: 1. `pushd` command saves the local path and change curdir to the server path. 2. `setlocal` command "saves" the server path. 3. `popd` command correctly restores curdir to the local path. 4. The Batch file ends and an implicit `endlocal` is executed, so the curdir is tried to be restored to the server path saved by `setlocal` and the error is issued. This behavior of `setlocal/endlocal` over the current directory is described [here](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4436).

Comment: @Aacini: Wow, nice find about `endlocal` restoring the current dir! I immediately suspected that "crossmixed" `setlocal` in the example, however, in a makefile command list I'm getting the same mysterious `system cannot find...` error for `popd` (that's how I got here, a bit late to the party, tho), and there isn't any `setlocal` in sight in my case.